# Countable Choice And Countable Union Of Countable Sets Being Countable

Tags: set-theory

Quick Question: Does the countable union of countable sets being countable imply the axiom of countable choice?

Comment: Meaning: given a collection of nonempty subsets of the natural numbers, you can always choose a given element? You don't need the Axiom of Choice for that: just choose the smallest element.

Comment: No - This was discussed on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74743/countable-unions-and-the-axiom-of-countable-choice).

Comment: @barrycarter: What are you talking about? "axiom of countable choice" has a **very precise definition** that is not about a (countably) collection of subsets of natural numbers.

Comment: Too bad, we can't flag this as a duplicate of Asaf's question over at mathoverflow. Should someone in the future stumble upon this post: Read the [post cited by @DrJones](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74743/countable-unions-and-the-axiom-of-countable-choice) - it fully answers this question.